# Need help analytically solving an integral

Tags: calculus

For one part of a multiple-part problem, I need to analytically find the value of the integral 
$$I=\int_{x_L}^{x_R}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{-Ax + B - C/x}}$$
My professor gave us notes that:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{z + c}{z(1-z)}}dz=2\sqrt c E(-1/c)$$
and
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{(z + c)^{3}}{z(1-z)}}dz = \frac{2}{3}\sqrt c[(4c + 2) E(-1/c) - (c+1)K(-1/c)]$$
Could both be useful, where E is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind and K is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

So, I've tried factoring -Ax+B-C/x and integration by parts but have not been able to get I into either of the two hinted-at forms. I'm basically looking for an explanation/hint about how either of those forms can be used.

Thanks!

Comment: rewrite it as $\sqrt{\frac{x}{-Ax^2+Bx - C}}$. Then look for a substitution $z = ax + b$ that will reduce it to the first of the two given integrals. However, i don't see how to handle the limits of integration, unless you also have expressions for $x_L, x_R$ that happen to coincide.